# GLSurfaceView Fullscreen not working on API 27

Tags: android, opengl-es, fullscreen, glsurfaceview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    tools:context="ui.wearing.WearingActivity">

    <GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </GLSurfaceView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The GLSufaceView won't work properly on Any Device with android 8.0 system** 
But it does **working for the devices with lower API ver.** than 27(8.0) !

The Problem is about the full screen mode:
[There's black area at the top of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33flv.png)
The activity main code for fullscreen mode:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_act);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could find any helpful logs to make this situation described in a better way. But this issue can be fixed with adding

`setRenderer(null);`

to your `GLSurfaceView` class instance.